# Node Application structure for subdomains

Tags: node.js

I am looking at building a website using node however my idea would be best with the use of subdomains. What i wanted to know is do i need to run each subdomain as a separate app and point to them with nginx?

Current Structure
- client
-- assets
--- js
--- css
--- img
- server
-- app
--- home
--- subapp1
--- subapp2
-- node_modules
-- server.js
-- config.js

The above structure is the thought that each app will run ny itself however they have common views that should be shared. Server.js will run them all. I just need to know if this is correct structure and if there is any cleaner or better alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up Nginx to reverse proxy to 2 NodeJS apps. Run 1 app on port 8081 for example (service1) and the other on 8082 (service2) like this:

```
upstream service1 {
  ip_hash;
  server localhost:8081;
}

upstream service2 {
  ip_hash;
  server localhost:8082;
}

server {
  listen          0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name     service1.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://service1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}

server {
  listen          0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name     service2.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://service2;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, `pm2` is a nice way to run multiple NodeJS apps simultaneously

Comment: Kevin thanks for your suggestion, so basically you mean to run each app by themselves using pm2?

Comment: Also is my folder structure logical regarding using nginx and pm2 as well as sharing template layouts